# Uniqueness proof: smallest element of an integers set

Tags: logic, proof-writing

How do you prove that the smallest element of a nonempty set of positive integers is unique? This is straightforward but how do you show it formally speaking?

Comment: Say there were two, $a$ and $b$.  Then, if $a\neq b$, we must have $a<b$ or $b<a$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like this:

Take a set of positive integers, ${S \subseteq \mathbb{N}}$. Assume that we have two positive integers ${n_1,n_2 \in S}$ with the property that ${n_1 \leq s\ \forall\ s \in S}$, and also ${n_2 \leq s\ \forall\ s \in S}$ (that is, both ${n_1,n_2}$ are smallest positive integers in the set ${S}$). This would mean that both ${n_1\leq n_2}$, and equally that ${n_2\leq n_1}$. The only thing one can conclude is that ${n_1=n_2}$. Note you asked how to prove if one existed, it would be unique: this does not necessarily prove one exists, though